# asp.net core mvc - unauthorized ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How unauthorized ajax request is processed/handled in asp.net core- MVC?
For me, When I make unauthorized ajax request it goes to the method and returns JSON data as undefined instead of giving the error or giving 401 status code.

I want to stop it to go to method and want to redirect it to the Login page.
I have tried using global error handler but error handler not catching any error and it goes to ajax method.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you add some code to show how you are making the AJAX request, and how you are handling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to find the different way to deal with this. When ajax request is made and it goes in the method, I checked at there that user is logged in or not. And if not I returned JSON response which I handle at client side and redirected to Login page.

Ideally, I was hoping that global Ajax error handler should pick up unauthorized access error and not go to ajax method at all and redirect to login page from global error handler only. But it seems it will go to method.